# In C can a called function make the caller function return?

Tags: c, sqlite, return, callstack

I'd like to find a way to make a function return (with a specific value) the function that called it. Is it possible in C? Maybe by checking the call stack?

Abstract example: suppose we have two functions

```
int called() {
    if (some_check_fails()) {
        /* here make caller() return -1 so "Hello world!\n" is not printed */
    }
}

int caller() {
    called();
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm searching for something to put in the `/* ... */` part.

Real-life example: the code I'm working one is a function that exports data in a SQLite file. This means a lot of calls to the SQLite API that need their return values checked *each time*. The result is an awfully looking and far too long function like this where the `if (resp_code != SQLITE_OK)` part repeats on and on:

```
sqlite3 *db;
char *err_msg;

/* Open the database in read-write mode, create it if not exists yet */
int resp_code = sqlite3_open_v2(filename, &db,
                                SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE,
                                NULL);
if (resp_code != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "SQLite error: cannot open database %s, %s\n", filename,
            sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return OMG_ERROR_HERE;
}

/* Create table */
char *query_table = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sometable; "
                    "CREATE TABLE sometable "
                    "(value int, data TEXT);";
resp_code = sqlite3_exec(db, query_table, 0, 0, &err_msg);
if (resp_code != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "SQLite error: %s\n", err_msg);
    sqlite3_free(err_msg);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return OMG_ERROR_HERE;
}

/* Prepare statement */
char *query = "INSERT INTO sometable VALUES (@i, @s);";
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
resp_code = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, 150, &stmt, NULL);
if (resp_code != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "SQLite error: %s\n", err_msg);
    sqlite3_free(err_msg);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return OMG_ERROR_HERE;
}

/* Start transaction */
resp_code = sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", 0, 0, &err_msg);
if (resp_code != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "SQLite error: %s\n", err_msg);
    sqlite3_free(err_msg);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return OMG_ERROR_HERE;
}

/* AND SO ON */
```

What I'd like is something like:

```
sqlite3 *db;
char *err_msg;

/* Open the database in read-write mode, create it if not exists yet */
int resp_code = sqlite3_open_v2(filename, &db,
                                SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE,
                                NULL);
return_this_function_if_not_ok(resp_code);

/* Create table */
char *query_table = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sometable; "
                    "CREATE TABLE sometable "
                    "(value int, data TEXT);";
resp_code = sqlite3_exec(db, query_table, 0, 0, &err_msg);
return_this_function_if_not_ok(resp_code);

/* Prepare statement */
char *query = "INSERT INTO sometable VALUES (@i, @s);";
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
resp_code = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, 150, &stmt, NULL);
return_this_function_if_not_ok(resp_code);

/* Start transaction */
resp_code = sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", 0, 0, &err_msg);
return_this_function_if_not_ok(resp_code);

/* AND SO ON */
```

---

**EDIT** 2015-12-21: I chose [FUZxxl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34386127/5292928) as best because it's the only one actually answering my question about returning the caller function. On the other hand [chux's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34387001/5292928) (based on [Rowland Shaw's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386037/in-c-can-a-called-function-make-the-caller-function-return#comment56513356_34386037) and [Ziffusion's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34386546/5292928)) is solving my SQLite problem the way I prefer.

**Big big big thanks to all of you!!**

Comment: You could use a macro to get the pre-processor to write the error checking code for you

Comment: What stops you from using the return value? Or are you looking for some way to create dynamic callbacks?

Comment: If you're feeling particularly masochistic today you could look at `setjmp` and `longjmp`.

Comment: By the way: this is what exceptions were invented to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a thing is not possible in C, but you can get close.

The identifier `__func__` is implicitly declared at the beginning of each function as

```
static const char __func__[];
```

It's value is the name of the current function as a string. You can write a function-like macro that implicitly passes the name of the caller to the callee. If the function that should receive the name of the caller is something like:

```
void error_check_fun(const char *function, int code, int result);
```

you can write a macro like this:

```
#define error_check(code, result) error_check_fun(__func__, code, result);
```

Similarly, `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are macros that expand to the current source file and line respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
#define return_this_function_if_not_ok(db, sql_code, sql_msg, code) \
    if ((sql_code) != SQLITE_OK) { \
        fprintf(stderr, "SQLite error: %s\n", (*sql_msg)); \
        sqlite3_free(sql_msg); \
        sqlite3_close(db); \
        return (code); \
    }

sqlite3 *db;
char *err_msg;

/* Open the database in read-write mode, create it if not exists yet */
int resp_code = sqlite3_open_v2(filename, &db,
                                SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE,
                                &err_msg);
return_this_function_if_not_ok(db, resp_code, err_msg, OMG_ERROR_HERE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Recommend something like [Rowland Shaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386037/in-c-can-a-called-function-make-the-caller-function-return#comment56513356_34386037) and [@Ziffusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34386546/2410359)

Call a function that packs in the data and handles common house-keeping.

```
int foo(char *err_msg, int code) {
  if (msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "SQLite error: %s\n", err_msg);
    sqlite3_free(err_msg);
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "SQLite error: %s\n", "Default error message");
  }
  sqlite3_close(db);
  return code;
}

resp_code = sqlite3_exec(...);
if (resp_code != SQLITE_OK) return foo(err_msg, OMG_ERROR_HERE);
...
resp_code = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, 150, &stmt, NULL);
if (resp_code != SQLITE_OK) return foo(NULL, OMG_ERROR_HERE);
```

---

Suggest further, include file and line number.  This is something I found very useful.

```
int bar(char *err_msg, int code, const char *file, int line) {
  fprintf(stderr, "SQLite error:%s, Code:%d, File:%s, Line%d\n",
     err_msg ? err_msg : "Default error message", code, file, line);
  }
  sqlite3_free(err_msg);
  sqlite3_close(db);
  return code;
}

#define foo(err_msg, code, file, line) bar((err_msg), (code), __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

Comment: This answer actually solves my ugly-code problem most easily, big thanks :) but it's not answering directly to the question about returning the caller function, so I cannot choose it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setjmp()/longjmp()` to get this effect, although not exactly like how you are wanting:

```
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int check_result;

int some_check_fails() {
    return check_result;
}

int called(jmp_buf buf) {
    if (some_check_fails()) {
        longjmp(buf,1);
    }
}

int caller() {
    jmp_buf buf;
    if (setjmp(buf)==0) {
        called(buf);
        printf("Hello world!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        printf("Failure\n");
        return -1;
    }
}

int main() {
    check_result = 0;
    caller();
    check_result = 1;
    caller();
}
```

Output:

```
Hello world!
Failure
```

This technique does avoid putting checks in multiple places, effectively implementing a type of exception handling mechanism.  However, there are other ways to clean up the code without resorting to this.